# Spring Boot PathVariable Validation Message

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot

I want to validate the PathVariable of an endpoint. Actually, it's not a validation because it's done by the java itself. For example, if the PathVariable type is Integer and I pass String to it, it will throw something like this: `Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.lang.Long]...` - this it the response message. How can I set custom message (ex: The age must be a number)? I know that I can create a custom validator and use it with annotation but as I have many endpoints, I will have to create a really big amount of validators for every single PathVariable - looks like something is not OK because I know there must be a just easier way. Am I wrong?

Comment: Do you mean PathParam? Because entering a `String` as PathVariable just means a different endpoint and should give you a 404.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a handler for the `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException` that is thrown:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {
    @Inject
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String handleTypeMismatch(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException e) {           
        // Return custom message from messageSource using e.getRequiredType()
    }
}
```